# Explain the below Array Of consecutive Number

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm

I have the below example which prints a 2 dimensional array of consecutive numbers.

My Question is how should i determine the number that is multiplied by **i**
in the below example ( Which is **3** in this case) in order to print an array of consecutive numbers.

It always seems to be i * [length of the second dimension of the array] + j.

**If more explanation is needed please tell me**

```
    public class test
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        populate();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static void populate()
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[4, 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = i * 3 + j;
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By replacing `3` with `matrix.GetLength(1)`?

Comment: `3` is the length of the second dimension of your array. So you get `0,1,2` and then `3,4,5`..., so what is your question exactly?

Comment: @MattBurland I am asking how should i Know the number that is multiplied by i  and added to j to generate 0,1,2 and then 3,4,5. Meaning how should i determine x in the following matrix[i, j] = i * X + j;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, presumably the idea is to end up with:

```
        | 0   1   2  <-- j
        ------------
      0 | 0,  1,  2
i ->  1 | 3,  4,  5
      2 | 6,  7,  8
      3 | 9, 10, 11
```

So this is simple math. Your columns are `j` and your rows are `i`. `j` is going to run 0,1,2. So in your first row (where `i == 0`) you need:

```
0 * 3 + 0 = 0,  0 * 3 + 1 = 1,  0 * 3 + 2 = 2
```

Now for your next row (`i==1`), you need to *start at 3* and then add `j` to it. So you get:

```
1 * 3 + 0 = 3,  1 * 3 + 1 = 4,  1 * 3 + 2 = 5
```

For the third row (`i==2`) you are going to need to *start at 6* which is simply the row ordinal (`2`) times the width of each row (`3`), so you get:

```
2 * 3 + 0 = 6,  2 * 3 + 1 = 7,  2 * 3 + 2 = 8
```

Now if your table was wider, and you needed, for example:

```
0,  1,  2,  3
4,  5,  6,  7
...
```

I hope it's pretty obvious now that your formula would need to be:

```
i * 4 + j
```

So, yes, the number you are multiplying by is the width of each row. And that will be the same as the length of your second array dimension. So you could make your formula be:

```
i * matrix.GetLength(1) * j
```